# SPARQL - disable alphabetical order comparing entities' ID

Tags: compare, sparql, wikidata

I am using Wikidata to get a lists of elements. At some point, I will need to update the lists with what will have been added to Wikidata in the meantime.
I have the ID of the latest entity, so I want to select only those with a higher number. That's the only way I found in order to get what I want: is there an other way?

There are 21 top models on Wikidata. Let's say I want to select those who have been added after Claudia Schiffer (Q76717).
Here's what I managed to do (you can try it [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ865851%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28str%28%3Fitem%29%3E%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ76717%27%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cfr%22%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel)):

```
    SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
    WHERE {
      ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q865851 .
      FILTER (str(?item)>'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q76717')
      SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr"}
    }
    GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

The problem is that, instead of having 20 results, I only have 1. I understand why (alphabetical comparisons) but I can't think of a solution to get a real comparison.

Would there be a way to extract the entity ID and compare its algebric value and not its caracters? Or do you see another way of reaching my aim?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Well, the most obvious way is to change your FILTER condition:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE {
  VALUES (?id) {(76717)}
  ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q865851 .
  FILTER (xsd:integer(STRAFTER(STR(?item), "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q")) > ?id)
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr"}
}
# GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fid%29%20%7B%2876717%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ865851%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28xsd%3Ainteger%28STRAFTER%28STR%28%3Fitem%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ%22%29%29%20%3E%20%3Fid%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cfr%22%7D%0A%7D%0A%23%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel)

However, I'm not sure this is the best way. I will do some research.

---

Unfortunately, Wikidata:

- provides only `schema:dateModified` for items (try [this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fmodified%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ865851%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20schema%3AdateModified%20%3Fmodified%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cfr%22%7D%0A%7D%0A%23%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel)),
- [does not provide](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T151539) `schema:dateCreated` of items.

Analogously, Wikidata:

- provides provenance information for some retrieved statements (try [this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FpropertyLabel%20%3Fupdate%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ865851%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3FonProperty%20%3Fstatement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20prov%3AwasDerivedFrom%2Fpr%3AP813%20%3Fupdate%20.%0A%20%20%3Fproperty%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20%3FonProperty%20.%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cfr%22%7D%0A%7D)),
- [does not provide](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T136799) provenance information for all statements.

Comment: You could use the provenance information of the statement, i.e. when it was created - I guess `prov:generatedAtTime` might exist

Comment: @AKSW, I hoped, but it seems they only use [pr:P813](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P813) for some retrieved statements, [this](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T136799) task is of the lowest priority...  Please post an answer, if you know a good way to get such "incremental updates" of Wikidata in SPARQL!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved it! :)
It seems simple now that I see it, but I didn't know this VALUES part.

Comment: @RenaudML, [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) is a way to substitute a value or values to variable. You can remove this line and write `76717` instead of another occurrence of `?id` directly.

Comment: @RenaudML, I have finished my "research".